# Unable to ping/ssh/telnet new EC2 linux instance

Tags: amazon-web-services

I just created a new EC2 instance. Once the instance is running and has passed health checks, I try to connect to its IP via telnet on port 22 (because SSH wasn't working I'm going to basics).

I have:

- opened security group's ports 22 and 80
- create custom security group's ICMP rule for protocol echo reply
- checked AWS statuses for outages -> none

The telnet line is:

**telnet [PUBLIC IP ADDRESS] 22** => Connect failed

also tried

**telnet [PUBLIC IP ADDRESS] 80** => Connect failed

I did the same for another existing instance and it works. What else can I still check for?

Comment: Depending on the distro, make sure that the firewall of the actual instance isn't blocking anything.

Comment: @BelminFernandez but here it seems to be blocking everything..

Comment: @BelminFernandez but it's a *new* instance... Not possible to check notables when you can't access the new instance.

Comment: @greener does the telnet connection say "connection timed out" or "connection refused"?  Is this your own AMI or a distro?

Comment: I believe I am correct in asserting that cross-posting is discouraged. http://superuser.com/questions/922998/unable-to-connect-telnet-new-ec2-instance

Comment: @Michael Ah, totally modes that this was initial connection.

Comment: *autocorrect fail, notables = iptables

Comment: Could you please show us your inbound & outbound rules on your security group that is associated with the instance?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out the bit of documentation that helped was this:

*[EC2-VPC] Check the route table for the subnet. You need a route that sends all traffic destined outside the VPC (0.0.0.0/0) to the Internet gateway for the VPC.*

[EC2 TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html)

I added the route and was able to SSH into the instance.